# How can I delete my cloned object after a certain amount of time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to programming. I want to spawn `punchAttack` from a prefab and then destroy it after a few seconds to remove clutter. Everything i have tried has made it so I can no longer instantiate any punch attacks after the destroy counter has reached 0. How can I delete each instance after it has been alive for 2 seconds?
Thanks in advance!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;

public class PunchAttack : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject punchAttack;
    private GameObject cloneOb;
  
    

   
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            Instantiate(punchAttack, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            Task.Delay(10).ContinueWith(t => delete());
            
        }
    }
    void delete()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destroy function has one optional time parameter

```
Destroy(GameObject, time);
```

Use it like this

```
 void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            //save instantiated punchAttack object into a variable and pass it in delete function
            GameObject go = Instantiate(punchAttack, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            delete(go);
            
        }
    }
    void delete(GameObject go)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject, 2f);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with this

```
Gameobject g = Instantiate(punchAttack, transform.position, transform.rotation)as Gameobject;

Destroy(g, Yourdelaytime);
```

so your script wil be like this :

```
void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            Gameobject g = Instantiate(punchAttack, transform.position, 
            transform.rotation)as Gameobject;

            Destroy(g, Yourdelaytime);
        }
    }
```

or you can make `Destroy(gameobject,YourDelayTime)` on `punchAttack prefab` with new Script